# adding a news ticker with a custom API feed

Tags: html, css, api, ticker

I have a custom news api which I own and I want to have a ticker on my site that will display the headlines from this API.  I have absolutely no idea where to start so any help would be greatly appreciated.

The API is here - https://script.googleusercontent.com/macros/echo?user_content_key=KvzaGPMZrJGUEWaEDrntwDsJB4ebk6cMKYQanyYZfDZYTacpxJM1uqcFLZlt7gRijBZ3J7FHj19AO45LNHwc-5mGOgupfNium5_BxDlH2jW0nuo2oDemN9CCS2h10ox_1xSncGQajx_ryfhECjZEnHo4zSljUNFhSoLskb1EQanQchoZ0NK0UbXpeUuc4BiuTzRrejx-uuzJ3Cy4pYPEhqLnfkWl2vSqJU1x8zviIhBUyyBe7Vdo1A&lib=MiQfzcgZEeK-gt9DdQ9yMvEauh1FhrIJO

Does anyone have a relatively simple solution?  I am currently using the below ticker (but updating it manually) and I really want an automated solution?

style.css:

```
.slideText {
display: block;
width: 500px;
height: 30px;
background: red;
color: #fff;
overflow: hidden;
}
.slidingtext {
padding: 5px;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 15s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}

@keyframes example {
  from {transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 500, 5)}
  to {transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -344, 5)}
}
```

and then the html file:

```
<div class="slideText">
<div class="slidingtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
```

I really have no idea how to integrate the two...

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read our [ask] page

Comment: I have edited this with more info - sorry it's very bare bones but I really have no idea...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for fetch in JS to get your info.

Here's a simple snippet which gets info from your API and console logs all the headlines that it finds. You can instead of course use that text to populate your ticker and perhaps set a timeout to call for an update every so often.

```js
const url =
  `https://script.googleusercontent.com/macros/echo?user_content_key=-WAEswRhz-A0GFJ7kVMHCtmEgGi3q5az_Vgw-M8X1TvM8Jer2UKhnDLhmiDCtGSKYwduFtp29EKPSP2NctqT6tB5DiSoHoStm5_BxDlH2jW0nuo2oDemN9CCS2h10ox_1xSncGQajx_ryfhECjZEnHo4zSljUNFhSoLskb1EQanQchoZ0NK0UbXpeUuc4BiuTzRrejx-uuzJ3Cy4pYPEhqLnfkWl2vSqJU1x8zviIhBUyyBe7Vdo1A&lib=MiQfzcgZEeK-gt9DdQ9yMvEauh1FhrIJO`;

fetch(url).then((response) => {
  return response.json(); // convert to json
}).then(info => {
  const data = info.data;
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i].headline);
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I don;t know how to implement this into the tracker - can you help with this?

Comment: Put two copies of the headlines - perhaps separated with a dash or something - into the div that currently holds the Lorem Ipsum and use the keyframes: transform: translateX(0) at 0% and transform: translateX(-50%) at 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I think the timing of the animation is a bit off but combining your code with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73190296/600486) above (by @A Haworth) should get you close to what you are looking for.

see code below

```js
$(function() {
  const url =
    `https://script.googleusercontent.com/macros/echo?user_content_key=-WAEswRhz-A0GFJ7kVMHCtmEgGi3q5az_Vgw-M8X1TvM8Jer2UKhnDLhmiDCtGSKYwduFtp29EKPSP2NctqT6tB5DiSoHoStm5_BxDlH2jW0nuo2oDemN9CCS2h10ox_1xSncGQajx_ryfhECjZEnHo4zSljUNFhSoLskb1EQanQchoZ0NK0UbXpeUuc4BiuTzRrejx-uuzJ3Cy4pYPEhqLnfkWl2vSqJU1x8zviIhBUyyBe7Vdo1A&lib=MiQfzcgZEeK-gt9DdQ9yMvEauh1FhrIJO`;

  fetch(url).then((response) => {
    return response.json(); // convert to json
  }).then(info => {
    const data = info.data;
    var idx = 0;

    const interval = setInterval(function() {
      $("#headline").html(data[idx].headline);
      
      console.log(data[idx].headline);  
      idx++;

      if (idx >= data.length) {
        idx = 0;
      }
    }, 8000);

    /*
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      console.log(data[i].headline);  
    }
    */
  });
});
```

```css
.slideText {
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slidingtext {
  padding: 5px;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 8s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}

@keyframes example {
  from {
    transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 500, 5)
  }
  to {
    transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -344, 5)
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideText">
  <div id="headline" class="slidingtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this.  For some reason it works on stack overflow (when I Run Code Snippet) but when I run this on the site all I get is "Lorem Ipsum...".  Any ideas?

Comment: no idea; you need to see what errors you get in the console.

Comment: I'm getting the error "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $" and nothing is returning in the console log.

Comment: did you include the jquery library like I did? (see the first line of code in the HTML portion?)